# font and position of frametitle text

Tags: beamer, frame-title

Based on the answer in this thread:

[horizontal line below frametitle and framesubtitle on beamer slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405365/horizontal-line-below-frametitle-and-framesubtitle-on-beamer-slides)

I copied and modified it a bit, however what I would be needing is (as in the picture below) to change the font of the frametitle to Arial Black, and also the position, I played around a lot, but unfortunately could not manage to do his. Help would be much appreciated.
The code as it is now:

```
    \documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=Black}
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=red}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip0.3cm%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.7cm plus1fil,vmode]{frametitle}%
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-4.6cm\relax}%
        \hspace{0.6cm}
\vspace{0.1cm}
    \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\insertframetitle%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
        \strut\par%
      \else
        \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
      \fi%%
        \end{minipage}%
        \hspace{0.6cm}
\vspace{-0.3cm}
\begin{minipage}{2.5cm}%
\hfill\vspace{-0.3cm}
            \hfill
            \includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{example-image-b}%
        \end{minipage}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \vskip1ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt,wd=\textwidth]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- in order to use Arial Black for the title, you could switch to lualatex or xelatex and use the fontspec package. This allows you to use any font installed on your computer, e.g. Arial Black.
- for the positioning I suggest to specify the height of both minipages and align the content at the bottom

---

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
    
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=Black}
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=red}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\arialblack}{Arial Black}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\arialblack}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip0.3cm%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth]{frametitle}%
    \begin{minipage}[t][1.2cm][b]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-4.6cm\relax}%
        \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\insertframetitle%
        \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
          \strut\par%
        \else
          \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
        \fi%%
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t][1.2cm][b]{2.5cm}
      \hfill\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{example-image-b}%
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt,wd=\textwidth]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
    content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @Parinn You're welcome!