# beamer, titlepage, logo and horizontal line

Tags: beamer, spacing, graphics, frame-title

I have a beamer presentation, where here ([font and position of frametitle text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672245/font-and-position-of-frametitle-text/672246?noredirect=1#comment1670648_672246))
I got help defining the correct frametitle environment.
Now what I would like to have is the horizontal line and the logo also on the titlepage (about the same position if possible, see picture below). I tried playing around with "%\textcolor{red}{\rule{16cm}{1mm}}"  and also doing an empty frametitle environment on the titlepage however that didn't lead to anything.

the background picture that I used: https://images.pexels.com/photos/1323550/pexels-photo-1323550.jpeg and the code as it is now

```
\documentclass[mathserif,11pt]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=Black}
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=red}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref,graphicx}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.722, 0.435, 0.698}% Rule colour
\newfontfamily{\arialblack}{Arial Black}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\arialblack}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip0.3cm%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth]{frametitle}%
    \begin{minipage}[t][1.2cm][b]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-4.6cm\relax}%
        \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\insertframetitle%
        \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
          \strut\par%
        \else
          \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
        \fi%%
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t][1.2cm][b]{2.5cm}
      \hfill\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{example-image-b}%
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt,wd=\textwidth]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother
% Let's get started

\author[Author, Author]
{
  Author
}
\usepackage{tikz}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

{
 \usebackgroundtemplate{%

 \begin{picture}(100,300)
\includegraphics[width=1.0\paperwidth]{pexels-photo-1323550.jpeg}
     \end{picture}
 }%
  \begin{frame}[plain] 
    %\textcolor{red}{\rule{16cm}{1mm}}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
    \begin{center}

\end{center}
\end{frame}
%-----------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are anyway loading the tikz package, you could use it to design your title page background.

Other comments:

- the `mathserif` option is obsolete, use `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` instead
- you don't need to load the `hyperref` and `graphicx` packages, beamer loads them for you
- if you want the line and the logo on all frames, I wouldn't make them part of the frametitle, but use the headline instead.

---

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[
%mathserif,
11pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=red}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{hyperref,graphicx}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.722, 0.435, 0.698}% Rule colour
\newfontfamily{\arialblack}{Arial Black}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\arialblack}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip0.3cm%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth]{frametitle}%
    \begin{minipage}[t][1.2cm][b]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-4.6cm\relax}%
        \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\insertframetitle%
        \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
          \strut\par%
        \else
          \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
        \fi%%
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t][1.2cm][b]{2.5cm}
      \hfill\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{example-image-b}%
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt,wd=\textwidth]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother
% Let's get started

\author[Author, Author]
{
  Author
}
\usepackage{tikz}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begingroup
 \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
    \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}};
    \draw[red,line width=0.1cm] ([yshift=-1.7cm]current page.north west) -- ++(\paperwidth,0);
    \node[anchor=north east] at ([xshift=-0.2cm,yshift=-0.2cm]current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{example-image-b}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \begin{frame}[plain] 
    
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
    \begin{center}

\end{center}
\end{frame}
%-----------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Sam, thank you so much, you have helped me tremendously!

Comment: @Parinn You're welcome!